# Rally: Limit results coming back in AttributeDropdown

Tags: rally

I am working on an app that uses the AttributeDropdown component of the App SDK. The dropdown has over 1,000 items in it which is making it very difficult to use. Is there a way to limit the results coming back in the dropdown?

```
//Create dropdowns
var jiraDropdownConfig = {
    type: "Story",
    attribute: "c_JiraIds",
    showLabel: true,
    label: "Jira Release: ",
    width: 350
};
jiraDropdown = new rally.sdk.ui.AttributeDropdown(jiraDropdownConfig, rallyDataSource);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the AttributeDropdown in SDK1 uses a primitive endpoint to populate the allowed values that does not support paging.  Can you by any chance use the [FieldValueComboBox](http://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc3/doc/#!/api/Rally.ui.combobox.FieldValueComboBox) in SDK2?  The SDK2 combobox is paged and supports type ahead searching.